# Python - Look within an object in a list

Tags: python

So I have a list called trucks, that has an object truck inside.
So trucks = [truck1, truck2, truck3].

And each truck is a list of its own and has a int volume attached to them, represented by index 1. So truck.volume would also be truck[1]. truck.volume is also defined btw.

```
def __larger_volume_truck(self, *truck):
    return truck[1]
```

so the way I am gonna use it is

```
for truck in trucks
    self.__larger_volume_truck(truck)
```

And it should return the index 1 of truck object within Trucks list.
Note that a truck object is a tuple, so truck1 = ('id', 50, 700).

**How do I do this?**

Comment: The single asterisk form is used to pass a non-keyworded, variable-length argument list. Remove the `*` from `def __larger_volume_truck(self, *truck)` and it will work fine.

Comment: Also, it helps if you post the error message.

Comment: Is ```__larger_volume_truck``` an instance method of class Truck?